# When to use skew normal regression via MCMC (mixture models)?

Tags: regression, markov-chain-montecarlo, residuals, skewness, skew-normal-distribution

When do I use skew normal or skew t regression via MCMC? Do I use them when the data are heavily skewed, for example income data? Or do I fit a normal regression model first and inspect the residuals of the normal regression and if the residuals are skewed, then apply a skew normal regression?

Comment: @Silverfish: it's okay to add tags on older posts, but if you go through this effort, consider combining it with other useful edits: correcting grammar and formatting (e.g. in this case - capitalizing the first letter), removing "thanks", etc. Adding a tag while leaving an obviously imperfect post otherwise intact is borderline here, and such edits can be rejected in the future.

Comment: @amoeba understood, apologies - I thought the content of this question was interesting enough, and the question itself well-posed, that its resurrection would do no harm. I must be the opposite of a grammar nazi - didn't even register the missing capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

> when do i use skew normal or skew t Regression via MCMC?

If in that question you're just interested in the circumstances in which you'd use a skew-normal or a skew-t model, why specify the method of estimation (MCMC)? In respect of *when* to use it, why would it matter whether I used MLE or MCMC or methods of moments?

> Do I use them when the data are heavily skewed, for example income data?

It depends on which skew-normal and which skew-t you mean.

If you mean [this skew normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution), the skew normal isn't nearly skewed enough for typical income data.

In some circumstances, you might use it for the *log* of income data.

This [skew-t](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~kercheva/papers/skewedt.pdf) seems to be used for somewhat more skewed situations (it's not 100% clear that it's the same object you intend though - you should always give enough details for people to be certain of exactly the distribution you mean).

Azzalini's skew-t seems to be the above skew-normal divided by the square root of (an independent chi-square on its df). I don't think its the same distribution as the skew-t as in that paper I link above, though it, too, seems as if it is able to be more skew than the skew-normal. Azzalini$^{[1]}$ seems to have used the log-skew-t for income, suggesting that in general that this skew-t may itself not be skewed enough for incomes.

> Or do I fit a normal Regression model first and inspect the residuals of the normal Regression and if the residuals are skewed, then I apply a skew normal Regression?

A normal distribution almost *certainly* won't be suitable as a model for incomes.

[1]: A. Azzalini, T. Dal_Cappello and S. Kotz (2003). Log-skew-normal and log-skew-t distributions as models for family income data. J. Income Distribution, 11, no. 3-4, 12-20.

Comment: (+1) The fact that skewed data doesn't *necessarily* mean the residuals will be skewed suggests there might be some logic in the OP's suggestion of fitting the normal model first and seeing if that is good enough - particularly if the skew were less egregious than for income data. On the other hand, I suppose if one fits the SN immediately, and the skewness were near zero, this would show up in the parameter estimates. One option is [fit both models then perform e.g. a likelihood ratio test](http://www.ime.unicamp.br/rel_pesq/2008/pdf/rp13-08.pdf) .

Comment: The point about transformations, and (certain definitions of) SN not being able to cope with large skew, is an interesting one. Skew normal regression seems to get sold as an *alternative* to transforming variables. But if they're both "tools in the toolkit" rather than mutually exclusive, there are presumably edge cases where SN is unsuitable on its own but would work well after a simple transformation. I can imagine that sometimes being preferable to applying a more complex (less interpretable) transform to get better normality.

Comment: The skew normal (the Azzalini one, which is also the one in wikipedia) is limited to skewness between -1 and 1. While you'd expect the conditional skewness of income distributions (at least with a good model) to be lower than marginal skewness, I think it would have to be a much better model than I've seen for the skew normal to fit (outside some relatively narrow set of situations).

Comment: I used the model proposed by FRÜHWIRTH-SCHNATTER/PYNE (2011):"Bayesian inference for finite mixtures of univariate and  multivariate skew-normal and skew-t distributions".